# Catch MFC exception

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Trying to catch MFC exception with macros:

```
TRY
   {
      // Do something to throw an exception.
   }
   CATCH(CException, e)  
   {

   }
   END_CATCH
```

How to get this error description message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CException::GetErrorMessage. You get the text with this call.

Comment: No need to delete e when using MFC macros.